# Как вставить текст в таблицу, если его там нет (INSET IF NOT EXISTS)?

Tags: php

Мне нужно вставить текст в таблицу, если его там нет. Как это можно сделать?

Вот мой код:

```
$usersDB = new SQLite3("cache/".$usersDBFileName);
$usersDBQuery = $usersDB->query("INSERT INTO users(id,text_id) VALUES (NULL, $userid) ");
```

Вот как я создавал базу данных:

```
$usersDBQuery = $usersDB->query("
                CREATE TABLE users (
                id integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
                text_id text
                )
            ");
```

Comment: "если его там нет" - а если есть, то что? Именно если нет текста? не юзера?

Comment: *если его там нет* Как только возникает подобная задача, сразу следует вопрос: "А где в структуре таблицы уникальный индекс, а?"

Answer (score 0):

Укажем уникальную колонку при создании таблицы

```
$usersDBQuery = $usersDB->query("
                CREATE TABLE users (
                id integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
                text_id text UNIQUE
                )
            ");
```

Далее обновляем таким методом:

```
 $usersDBQuery = $usersDB->query("INSERT OR IGNORE users(text_id) VALUES ($userid)");
```

Comment: Спасибо, всё получилось